# How to sort ng-repeat by some arrays?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following:

```
$scope.filterObj = {"status":["active"],"categories":["u"]}
```

And object that I need to sort:

```
{"categories" : ["u", "a"], "status" : "active"}
```

I tried to filter this as:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (projects | filter:filterObj.status:item.status) | orderBy : 'created_at'">
```

This sample works for one item:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (projects | filter:{ status : 'finished' }) | orderBy : 'created_at'">
```

But not fo array

Comment: My object is: `{"status":["finished"],"categories":[]}`

Comment: I tried also: `ng-repeat="item in filtered = (projects | filter:{status : filterObj.status}) | orderBy : 'created_at'"`

Comment: how about `filter: filterObj`?

Comment: Does not work, but I have found solution, will post later